# Issue with on click in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

How can we perform onclick event on href, I wrote the following code but ot does not perform any action. What's wrong with my code ?

```
<a href="javascript:sendCategoryDetails()" id="maillocation" data-mini="true" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-inline="true">Send Category Details</a>
```

My Java script code is as follows,

```
function sendCategoryDetails()
      {
         alert("control is here");
      }
```

Comment: Use the below line `<a href="javascript:sendCategoryDetails(); return false;" id="maillocation" data-mini="true" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-inline="true">Send Category Details</a>` Due to page post back the link is not displaying your alert message.

Comment: Works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9Scwz/)

Comment: Work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/kktLt/

Comment: This code works for me

Comment: your code will work perfectly if your sendCategoryDetails() is located at proper location in your js file. Are you sure you haven't wrapped it in some onload() function and have included the related js files properly? see http://jsfiddle.net/RN5dh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html

```
<a href="javascript:void();" onClick="sendCategoryDetails();" id="maillocation" data-mini="true" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-inline="true">Send Category Details</a>
```

<kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ht6Ym/2617/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<a href="#" id="maillocation" data-mini="true" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-inline="true" onClick="sendCategoryDetails()">Send Category Details</a>
```

javascript:
has been disabled for security reasons in new versions of most browsers or its disabled by defualt

Answer (score 0):

try this
 Send Category Details

```
    <script>
 function sendCategoryDetails()
 {
   window.location.href("URL");
  }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your anchor html to this

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="sendCategoryDetails()" id="maillocation" data-mini="true" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-inline="true">Send Category Details</a>
```

OR using jQuery

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"  id="maillocation" data-mini="true" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-inline="true">Send Category Details</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#maillocation').click(function(){
     sendCategoryDetails()
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`href` attribute is used to `add link`.You cannot call the function on `href`

```
<a href="javascript:void();" id="maillocation" data-mini="true" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-inline="true" onClick="sendCategoryDetails()">Send Category Details</a>
```

`href="#"` will post the same page.It adds # in your url not good

`href="javascript:void();"` use this to avoid

Answer (score -1):

Use `javascript:document.location.href=function_name();`

#### Check this <kbd>**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H95GU/)**</kbd>

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function sendCategoryDetails(){
         alert("control is here");
      }
</script>

<a href="javascript:document.location.href=sendCategoryDetails();" 
   id="maillocation" 
   data-mini="true" data-role="button" 
   data-theme="b" data-inline="true">Send Category Details</a>
```

## 100% worked, dont know why minus vote!